# Application crashing when using <Run Text={Binding ...}/> with certain properties in a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am using `<Run Text={Binding ...}/>` inside a `TextBlock` in order to concatenate 2 strings (one which is hard coded, the other one is a binding expression on a property). This is being done in a `DataTemplate` :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MarketOrderDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Item icon TODO: Add Icon-->
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Stretch="Fill" Source="../../Images/thumb_icon-mineral-protoss.png" />

            <Separator Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />

            <!-- Item information -->
            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">
                    <Run Text="Item Name : "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
                    <Run Text="Item ID : "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Item.ItemID}"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">
                    <Run Text="Item Type : "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Item.ItemType}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>

            <Separator Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />

            <!-- Market order information -->
            <Grid Grid.Column="4" Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">
                    <Run Text="Market Order ID : "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding OrderID}"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
                    <Run Text="Price : "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">
                    <Run Text="Volume Remaining : "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding VolumeRemaining}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This works in the Item Information part of my `DataTemplate` (with bindings on `Item.ItemName`, `Item.ItemID`, `Item.ItemType`) without any problems. When I try to do the same with the Market Order Information part of my `DataTemplate` (with bindings on `OrderID`, `Price`, `VolumeRemaining`) though, it makes the application crash for some reason.

It works well if I just set the `Text`property on my `TextBlock` with the same binding expression, but I do not know why it makes the application crash with the `<Run Text={Binding ...}/>` syntax on the Market Order Info part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not show your view model or the error so I can only suspect that it's because your property is read-only and `Run` by default bind both ways. Change binding to OneWay

```
<Run Text="{Binding VolumeRemaining, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: This worked, but I do not have a `readonly` property in my viewmodel. `OrderID` is a `uint`, `Price` is a `float` and `VolumeRemaining` is a `uint`.

Comment: Type does not matter. What matters is do these properties have public setter as well as getter? In order for property to be bound both ways it **must have public getter and setter**

Comment: They did not have setters, that's why! Thanks for your help!